# add parameters into the URL using simpleMcrypt

Tags: php, get

I'm using simpleMcrypt to hide the email address of a user into an url.

Is it possible to add more parameters inside the kind of URL ?

```
www.mysite.com/valid/?cf_m=79d9U12bQ3VXagx1kJgduoepvdcY0dvSKEtk/qn7ghE=
```

Comment: OK, I have just to put &chambre=1 ie

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have just to put &chambre=1 ie –